# Create matrix with values equal to function of row and col indexes

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a 6x6 matrix with the cell values equal to the sum of the row index and he col index.  I can do this using loops, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this using vector functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `outer` function with "+":

```
outer(1:6, 1:6, "+")

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    2    3    4    5    6    7
[2,]    3    4    5    6    7    8
[3,]    4    5    6    7    8    9
[4,]    5    6    7    8    9   10
[5,]    6    7    8    9   10   11
[6,]    7    8    9   10   11   12
```

Incidentally, this is basically a shortcut for the following vectorized approach:

```
matrix(rep(1:6, 6) + rep(1:6, each = 6), nrow = 6)
```

Comment: Much prefer the first.  Couldn't get it out of my head that I was trying to do a cross join.  Sometimes the terminology just gets in the way.

Comment: @NickLarsen The "cross join" approach in R would use `expand.grid`, e.g. `expand.grid(x = 1:6, y = 1:6) %>% mutate(total = x + y)`, and would return a 36-row df rather than a 6x6 matrix. Interestingly, tidyr now has a `crossing` function that workds like `expand.grid` but returning a `tbl_df`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another possibility:

```
m <- matrix(NA,6,6)
m <- col(m)+row(m)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    2    3    4    5    6    7
#[2,]    3    4    5    6    7    8
#[3,]    4    5    6    7    8    9
#[4,]    5    6    7    8    9   10
#[5,]    6    7    8    9   10   11
#[6,]    7    8    9   10   11   12
```